# Visual Studio 2010 - create silent MSI for project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

We have an Outlook addin that we created in Visual Studio 2010 in C#.  When publishing, we're given an exe that does not allow for any quiet installation processes - none of the typical command switches work.

How do I generate a silent MSI instead of the default setup exe?

Comment: Silently modifying the user's machine and copying executable files is evil.  What are you trying to hide?  UAC was designed to stop you from doing this.

Comment: @HansPassant This is a corporate deployment through Configuration Manager.  We can't deloy to a thousand machines if every user has to go through a setup process...

Comment: Leave this up to corporate IT staff, they always have strict rules about exactly when and how changes are pushed.  They can ask questions about it at serverfault.com

Comment: @HansPassant I *am* part of the corporate IT staff.  We don't have an app dev team, so this add-in was thrown together by me and a couple other system administrators, hence this question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution I was looking for in an MSDN help article.

[Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)

This is all I wanted to do - create an MSI instead of using the provided exe (which does NOT include an integrated MSI or other packages).  This allows for flexible, scalable deployments without user interaction, regardless of user that is logged in to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it just works if you use only the MSI file. The setup.exe installs the prerequisites and then launches the MSI file. There is no good answer I can give about the prerequisites because they may all be different, but in general you just use whatever the details of the redist tell you in docs or a web search, installing prereqs by administrators etc.

It's an MSI, you publish it to the machine (I think that's the group policy description) and in fact the install is required to be silent and will give you an error if you attempt to show UI, the message being "This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic." 
In other words when the administrator has defined the install parameters etc the user cannot change them.